# insertAt() not working for singly linked list in node.js

Tags: node.js, singly-linked-list

I have some FIFO calculations to be followed so I am using [singly-linked-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/singly-linked-list) 
When I am trying to insert data at specific location using insertAt(index,data) method it just does not work.

```
 var LinkedList = require('singly-linked-list')
 var testlist = new LinkedList();

 testlist.insertAt(1,'abc');
```

Output

```
{ 
    head: null,
    tail: null,
    size: 0,
    iterator: 
    { 
        list: [Circular], 
        currentNode: null 
    }
}
```

Please suggest me any fix or alternative for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module you are using [will not](https://github.com/jasonsjones/singly-linked-list/blob/479cc7b9d2f9447e74eed6377289228f24232457/index.js#L162) insert a new node at an index that is out of bounds based on the current size of the list.

You may have thought that `0` would never be out of bounds but it will be according to the condition in the source linked to above when the list is empty.

You could use the `insert` method instead, perhaps surrounded by a check to see if the list is empty or not.

Comment: What if I want to insert records at first 3 positions and my list is not empty

Comment: @PriyankaPawar - If your list is not empty the `insertAt` method should work fine. See [this example](https://tonicdev.com/56e7f57aea28eb11002a6908/56e7f57aea28eb11002a6909).

Comment: ohh yes. Thank you so much